# How to handle 30 request using single wcf operation?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, design-patterns

I am bit stuck somewhere while designing my solution and therefore need your expertise and suggestions.

The problem is: I have 30 type of requests each having different parameters therefore i am treating these 30 request as 30 different request input but response is same for all request types.

Now I need to create one operation inside my existing wcf service which can cater all 30 types of requests.

I am not getting how to cater this within single operation. I dont want to create the 30 operations to handle the request individually.

Comment: do you see possibility of all of these 30 request type to have common base class or can they implement a common interface or they are all having different structure and also differ on list of behaviors?

Comment: What's bad about method overloading or generics? That is if I understood you correctly.... :)

Comment: Is this an existing operation that you want to modify or are you going to create a new operation. If you are creating a new operation you can pass a enum as a param that would identify the request type and accordingly can be handled in your operation.

Answer (score 2):

If your request types all derive from the same type you can expose them polymorphically using the ServiceKnownTypes attribute:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(RequestFromThisGuy))]
[KnownType(typeof(RequestFromThisOtherGuy))]
public class UberRequest
{
    ...
}

[DataContract]
public class RequestFromThisGuy: UberRequest
{
    ...
}

[DataContract]
public class RequestFromThisOtherGuy: UberRequest
{
    ...
}
```

Then your service operation:

```
[OperationContract]
CommonResponseType DoSomething (UberRequest request)
```

Answer (score -1):

tricky tricky

```
public void MyOperation(List<InputType> inputs)
        { 
            // your stuffs here. 

        }
```

Comment: OP said the requests were all different.